# ajax not receiving session values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to update a progress bar from dynamic value($done) generated by f_backup.php and storing it in a session variable and caling it with ajax. Now i am not sure whether the call i am making is correct or not.
I am also getting an error:
 Undefined index: progress in C:\wamp\www\SDBMS\get_live_val.php on line 3

I would also like to show some animation in the progress bar but i dont know how to.
P.S: It would be very helpful for me if someone can show me some code snnipets of the places where i should edit.
I tried searching everywhere for my problem but nothing has come to my rescue.

Here is my code:

PHP (f_backup.php)

```
<?php
$total_tables=0;
$table_no=1;
$done=0;
$return='';
.
.
foreach($allTables as $table){
    .
    .
    .   
    for($i=0; $i<$num_fields; $i++){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            $return.='INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++){
                .
                .
                .
            }
            $return.=");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n";

    //calculating progress
    $done=($table_no/$total_tables)*100;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['progress']=$done;
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
    $table_no=$table_no+1;
}

    .
    .
?>
```

PHP (get_live_val.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['progress'];
exit();
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.progressbar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'f_backup.php',
    success: function(data){
    }
});

function progress(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_live_val.php',
        success: function(data){
            $("#progressbar").html(data);
            if(data<10){
                progress();
            }
        }
    });
}
progress();
</script>
```

Comment: `session_start()` in `f_backup.php` should be called in the beginning of the file, **not in the loop**. Remove `exit()` from `get_live_val.php`. And to sessions and ajax - I personally had problems many times in the session *synchronization* between the *synchronous* and *asynchronous* requests... Many times I had experienced the problem that a session variable set in synchronous request (that runs and finishes before the asynchronous one) is not then initialized or set within the asynchronous request afterwards (or between two async requests as well). Maybe this is the same case.

Comment: what would you have done in my place? I mean instead of using sessions?

Comment: i did what you said but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: The error is coming because the session does not contain the `progress` key when accessed within AJAX request. To just get rid of that notice, change `echo $_SESSION['progress'];` into `echo isset($_SESSION['progress']) ? $_SESSION['progress'] : '';` - but this will echo `''` (empty string) in case that session does not contain `progress` key - which will probably occur all the time. You need to solve that problem first.

Comment: I wouldn't have used *progress bar* - just simple loader (animated gif). If I first trigger the AJAX request for backup I would display this loader somewhere and on `success` or `complete` callback of backup request I would hide that loader. I understand that *progress bar* is more fancy, but is not worth the effort required to make it done properly.

Comment: :) can you show me how to implement that loader?(I an newbie to ajax actually)

Comment: also what might be the cases when the session variable does not contain the key?

Comment: You can find many examples on google how to implement `jquery ajax loader gif`. The reason for the session key not present within ajax requests is not that clear to me, sorry.